# HTTP requests fail for AngularJS/Express using Mongoose when it works with MongoJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose, mongojs

Need some help figuring out whats wrong with my code that's giving me 500 internal server error. Have been trying to figure out root cause myself since last 3 days to no avail. I've started learning the MEAN stack and have been experimenting with MongoJs and Mongoose. It's the latter setup that is not working. I've pasted below

a) gulpfile.js

b) Mongoose model/schema file (modelA.js),

c) httprequests.js file containing http requests using mongojs and mongoose {on the sideline -  is it a bad idea to have MongoJS and Mongoose codes in the same application???} and

d) angular script file (phone.js) . With the current coding my page (not mentioned below) using mongojs is working perfectly.

e) Error messages from Terminal and Chrome console

I'm new to MEAN and must be doing something basically wrong. Any help is sincerely appreciated.

**Gulpfile.js:**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
// historyapifallback to help overcome page refersh issue in angularjs
var historyApiFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');

gulp.task('serve', function() {
  browserSync.init({
        port: 3001,
        proxy: {
            target: "localhost:3000",
            ws: true,
            middleware: [ historyApiFallback() ]
        }
    });

  gulp.watch("./**/*.*").on('change', browserSync.reload);

});

gulp.task('default',['serve'], function() {
  var httpRequests = require('./scripts/mongo-mongodb/httprequests');

});
```

**modelA.js**

```
var mongoose = require('../../../node_modules/mongoose/lib');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var phoneSchema = new Schema({  
    age : Number,
    carrier : String,
    id : String,
    imageUrl : String,
    name : String,
    company: String,
    snippet : String
   });

/* global db */
module.exports = mongoose.model('Phone', phoneSchema);
```

**httprequests.js**

```
// load express module
var express = require("express");
// bootstrap express
var app = express();
//serve up index.html
app.use(express.static("./"));
// body parser for post requests
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Mongojs codes follows...

var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('test',['technology']);
// get all data from db
app.get('/techstack',function(req,res) {
  db.technology.find({},function(err,docs) {
    if (err) throw err;
    // console.log("im here");
    // console.log(docs);
    res.json(docs);
  });
});

// get data from db for specific id
app.get('/techstack/:id',function(req,res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  db.technology.findOne({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)},function(err,docs) {
  if (err) console.error;
  console.log(id);
  console.log("gulpfile");
  res.json(docs);
  });
});

app.post('/techstack', function(req,res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  db.technology.insert(req.body,function(err,docs) {
    if (err) console.error;
    res.json(docs);
  });
});

app.delete('/techstack/:id', function(req,res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  db.technology.remove({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)},function(err,docs) {
    // console.log(id);
  // db.technology.remove({ _id: id},function(err,docs) {  
  if (err) console.error;
  res.json(docs);
  });
});

app.put('/techstack/:id', function(req,res) {
  var id = req.params.id;
  db.technology.findAndModify(
    {
      query: {_id:mongojs.ObjectId(id)}, 
      update: {$set: {sl:req.body.sl, name:req.body.name, status:req.body.status, complexity:req.body.complexity}},
      new: true
    }, function (err, docs) {
      if (err) console.error;
      res.json(docs);
    });
});

//

// Mongoose codes follow...

var mongoose = require('../../../node_modules/mongoose/lib');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mean_db');
// var uri ='mongodb://localhost/mean_db';
// global.db = mongoose.createConnection(uri);

// var routes = require('../mongo-mongoose/routes');
var Phone = require('./modelA');

var router = express.Router();          // get an instance of the express Router

// // middleware to use for all requests
router.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // do logging
    console.log('Something is happening.');
    next(); // make sure we go to the next routes and don't stop here
});


router.get('/',function(req,res) {

  Phone.find({},function(err, docs) {
        if (err)
           res.send(err);

        res.send(docs);
  });
});

router.post('/',function(req, res) {

    var phone = new Phone();      // create a new instance of the Phone model
    // save the phone and check for errors
    phone.save(req.body,function(err,docs) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        res.json(docs);
    });
});

// REGISTER OUR ROUTES -------------------------------
// all of our routes will be prefixed with /phone-list
app.use('/phone-list', router);

app.listen(3000);
console.log('Listening on port 3000');
```

**phone.js**

```
'use strict';

var phone = angular.module('phone',[]);

phone.controller('View1Ctrl', function($scope,$http,$log,$location) {   


$scope.phone = {
    age : 0, 
    carrier : "",
    id : "",
    imageUrl : "",
    name : "",
    company: "",    
    snippet : ""
   };

$http.get('/phone-list')
    .then(function (response) {
        // console.log(response.data);
        $scope.phoneList = response.data;
      }
);

$scope.insertPhone = function () {

    $http.post('/phone-list', $scope.phone)
         .then(function (response) {
          console.log("inside post in phone.js");
          $scope.phoneList = response.data;
          $route.reload();
    });
};
```

**Error Messages:**

**On terminal**

```
14:18:51] Using gulpfile ~/github/mean-project/app/gulpfile.js
[14:18:51] Starting 'serve'...
[14:18:52] Finished 'serve' after 129 ms
[14:18:52] Starting 'default'...
Listening on port 3000
[14:18:52] Finished 'default' after 686 ms
[BS] Proxying: http://localhost:3000
[BS] Access URLs:
 ----------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3001
    External: http://10.0.1.12:3001
 ----------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3003
 UI External: http://10.0.1.12:3003
 ----------------------------------
Something is happening.
Something is happening.
Something is happening.
Something is happening.
Something is happening.
Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
/Users/akhileshmohan/github/mean-project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:98
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^ TypeError: callback is not a function
    at /Users/akhileshmohan/github/mean-project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:228:5
    at /Users/akhileshmohan/github/mean-project/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:135:7
    at /Users/akhileshmohan/github/mean-project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:504:5
    at /Users/akhileshmohan/github/mean-project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:666:5
    at handleCallback (/Users/akhileshmohan/github/mean-project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:96:12)
    at /Users/akhileshmohan/github/mean-project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:473:9
    at handleCallback (/Users/akhileshmohan/github/mean-project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:96:12)
    at resultHandler (/Users/akhileshmohan/github/mean-project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/bulk/unordered.js:420:5)
    at commandCallback (/Users/akhileshmohan/github/mean-project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:1194:9)
    at Callbacks.emit (/Users/akhileshmohan/github/mean-project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:119:3)
    at null.messageHandler (/Users/akhileshmohan/github/mean-project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:358:23)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/akhileshmohan/github/mean-project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:292:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
```

**On browser console**

```
angular.js:12011 POST http://localhost:3001/phone-list net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12011
n @ angular.js:11776
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:11571
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:16383
$eval @ angular.js:17682
$digest @ angular.js:17495
$delegate.__proto__.$digest @ VM95:844
$apply @ angular.js:17790
$delegate.__proto__.$apply @ VM95:855
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:25890
Sf @ angular.js:3497
d @ angular.js:3485
```

Comment: paste the complete error related data

Comment: A stacktrace of the error you're getting would help

Comment: Hi folks, Added the error responses from Terminal and Chrome console.

Comment: Badly need help guys...I'm not sure what is wrong in my code....please thanks